# Android Show Hide Fragment BottomNavigationView First Added Item Not Visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have a setup of 3 Fragments inside my main activity and want to navigate them using the BottomNavigationView. I want to add them once and then just switch between them without actually destroying the Fragments. Everything works fine except that the first fragment added to the SupportFragmentManager always disappears (tried changing the order so the problem is not with the Fragments themselves). Actually, it doesn't disappear but the last Fragment that occupied the container shows up.
Eg. I go to position 3, Fragment 3 shows up in the container and then click on position 1, Fragment 3 will still occupy the container. But if I tap position 2 Fragment 2 will appear. How I'm adding the Fragments:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment1); //whatever gets added here ends up being invisible
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment2);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment3);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

How I'm switching between them using the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigation_listener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        Fragment previousFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.bottom_navigation_bar_position1:
                selectedFragment = fragment1;
                break;
            case R.id.bottom_navigation_bar_position2:
                selectedFragment = fragment2;
                break;
            case R.id.bottom_navigation_bar_position3:                   
                selectedFragment = fragment3;
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(previousFragment).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(selectedFragment).commit();

        return true;
    }
};
```

The XML menu navigation:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar_position1"
    android:title="Title1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic1"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar_position2"
    android:title="Title2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic2"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar_position3"
    android:title="Title3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic3"
    />
```

Btw. just using replace() instead of show and hide works but that's not the goal...
I've also tested whether the first added Fragment exits (and doesn't get destroyed) and it indeed exists...
Thanks!

Comment: Do you find alternative way? without replace. I have the same problem. Please help me, my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448874/fragment-routing-in-bottom-navigation-view

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to show and hide fragment I solved the problem by managing the Fragments using a ViewPager and a SectionsPageAdapter. Once you link these two, use ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3) to make sure no Fragments get destroyed. My BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener looks like this now:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigation_listener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.bottom_navigation_bar_position1:
                tab_view_pager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.bottom_navigation_bar_position2:
                tab_view_pager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.bottom_navigation_bar_position3:
                tab_view_pager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set 0th position item selected for `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`. Find `Menu` bottom_navigation_bar_position1
I used this in my code, please refactor according to your needs

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
    this.onNavigationItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_doc));
```

Comment: It caused a null pointer exception for a Fragment.setNextAnim(int) in onStart. I solved it in a different way but I suspect that if you want to take this approach then it's the right direction. Thanks though!